# What is the best way to understand and analyze a multithreading code?

Tags: multithreading, code-analysis

I'm not looking for programming techniques. My question is rather about what is the best way to understand a code developed by a third party.

I have a code for an application in a specific language (it could be C/C++, Java, etc.). This code uses several threads to control different processes. The application generates a log that shows all calls to relevant functions for each thread.

I have to analyze this code to understand its operation and be able to make an improvement of the algorithm. I worked little with threads, so I do not know which is the most convenient way to start the analysis and follow the execution of each thread.

Could you give me any recommendation?

Comment: How well documented? How many threads?  Thread pools or explicit threads?  How do the threads communicate?  Are the threads tightly coupled or highly isolated?

Comment: There can only be 16 simultaneous threads. The documentation isn't good. It doesn't inform about thread and its communication. I still can not interpret how the threads communicate. So far, I could only observe that access to system resources is controlled by semaphores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to contact any of the code's original developers, having a conversation with them (by voice or by email) and asking them to describe how they intended things to work is always preferable to only trying to reverse-engineer their intent by looking at the code.  If you can't contact the developers directly, then perhaps there is a library-specific developer's forum or other on-line resource where you can discuss the library's structure with people who have experience using/debugging it.

If that's not an option (or if you've done that and still don't feel like you understand things well enough), then I often find that profiling (either via a profiling tool, or just by temporarily putting `printf()` [or similar] tracing-calls into the codebase at various places and seeing what gets printed when) is a good way to find out which parts of the code are actually being used at which stages of the program's execution.  That will help you confirm (or disprove) your theories about how the codebase works.  Knowing where and when each thread is spawned, where its entry-function is, and where/when it gets joined again by its parent thread are particularly useful.

Finally, start looking at the various pieces of data (e.g. objects and member variables) each thread examines and/or modifies, and how accesses to each those pieces of data is synchronized/serialized.  Assuming the code isn't buggy, the critical sections of the codebase are good indicators of where inter-thread communication is happening.